# How can I count the frequency of an answer in R?

Tags: r, crosstab

I have an db that look like this:

```
ID Group Drink
1   A      yes
2   A      no
3   A      NA
4   B      no
5   B      no
6   B      yes
```

and I would like measure how many people of group A drinks and how many people in group B drinks.

I am using `length()`, but this function returns `3` (`NA` is being considered = yes). How can I fix it?

Comment: You are looking for a cross tabulation which can be achieved using the `table` function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`table()` is one option:

```
db <- read.table(text = "ID Group Drink
1   A      yes
2   A      no
3   A      NA
4   B      no
5   B      no
6   B      yes", header = TRUE)

with(db, table(Drink))
with(db, table(Group, Drink))

> with(db, table(Drink))
Drink
 no yes 
  3   2 
> with(db, table(Group, Drink))
     Drink
Group no yes
    A  1   1
    B  2   1
```

Including the `NA` as a class is achieved by the `useNA` argument:

```
with(db, table(Drink, useNA = "ifany"))

> with(db, table(Drink, useNA = "ifany"))
Drink
  no  yes <NA> 
   3    2    1
```

You can of course store the objects returned by `table()` and access them as any other matrix/array:

```
tab <- with(db, table(Drink, useNA = "ifany"))
tab[1]
tab2 <- with(db, table(Group, Drink, useNA = "ifany"))
tab2[,1]
tab2[1,]

> tab <- with(db, table(Drink, useNA = "ifany"))
> tab[1]
no 
 3 
> tab <- with(db, table(Drink, useNA = "ifany"))
> tab[1]
no 
 3 
> tab2 <- with(db, table(Group, Drink, useNA = "ifany"))
> tab2[,1]
A B 
1 2 
> tab2[1,]
  no  yes <NA> 
   1    1    1
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's another way using `aggregate(...)`

```
aggregate(Drink~Group,df,function(x)sum(x=="yes"))
#   Group Drink
# 1     A     1
# 2     B     1
```

To get the percent that drink:

```
aggregate(Drink~Group,df,function(x)sum(x=="yes")/length(!is.na(x)))
#   Group     Drink
# 1     A 0.5000000
# 2     B 0.3333333
```

Answer (score 1):

`xtabs` is another option:

```
xtabs(~ Group + Drink, df)

#     Drink
#Group no yes
#    A  1   1
#    B  2   1
```

And in case you need a data.frame as output:

```
as.data.frame(xtabs(~ Group + Drink, df))

#  Group Drink Freq
#1     A    no    1
#2     B    no    2
#3     A   yes    1
#4     B   yes    1
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `d` is your data, and **assuming** `NA` **is considered** `yes` (since you stated that in your post), the proportions of drinkers are

```
> d$Drink[is.na(d$Drink)] <- 'yes'
> tab <- table(d$Group, d$Drink)
> tab[,'yes']/rowSums(tab)
##         A         B 
## 0.6666667 0.3333333
```

You could also play around with the `count` function in package `plyr`

```
> library(plyr)
> x <- count(d)
> cbind(x[x$Drink == 'yes', ], inGroup = count(d$Group)$freq)
#   Group Drink freq inGroup
# 2     A   yes    2       3
# 4     B   yes    1       3
```

Answer (score -1):

You could also make use of the function prop.table() which will add proportions to your table values that are returned.